# Azure Front door ignoring the error 403: Webapp is stopped(for azure functions not for webapp)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-front-door

I have one Azure front door. with one azure function in primary and one function app in the secondary region.It is working fine when both functions are up. it is distributing 50-50 loads to each region. but when I intentionally stop the primary function. all traffic should go to the secondary region. but it doesn't. "The web app is stopped " this page should not be hit by azure front door address when one region is down. but in my case "The web app is stopped" this message comes from a downed region.

I tried with web app with the same case scenario. and everything is working as expected. when I turn off one web app. all traffic goes to only the secondary region. azure front door doesn't call downed region web app. the same result I want for Azure function too. but it is not working for same configuration as I did for Webapp.

Here are my config pic.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the second backend is shown as healthy from front door ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found the solution. the reason was I was using proxy in azure functions. after removing proxy from the azure function it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167200/thomas) for providing the helpful suggestion to the OP let resolve the issue by checking the health status of the second backend from front door. Posting this resolution as an answer to help other community members.

Glad @[vishnuprajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18489604/vishnu-prajapati) that you had resolved the issue yourself by identifying the glitch using the Thomas comment and then removing the `proxy in Azure Functions`.